# Fast way read a large array from console, with memory constraint

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, byte, inputstream

I have this test data:

```
public class InputTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("90 22 11 4 5\n".getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
    }
```

and I need to read each digit from InputStream as an integer. I create this test:

```
@Test
public void read() throws IOException {
    int c;
    while ((c = System.in.read()) != '\n') {
        int i = readInt(c);
        if (i != -1)
            System.out.print(i);
    }
}

private static int readInt(int c) {
    int ret = 0;
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return ret * 10 + c - '0';
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And I have this output: `90221145` - I print each int to console. But I need separate digits like in source string - `90 22 11 4 5`

I can change it to:

```
@Test
public void read() throws IOException {
    int c;
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    while ((c = System.in.read()) != '\n') {
        int i = readInt(c);
        if (i != -1) {
            b.append(i);
        }else {
            b.append(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(b.toString());
}

private static int readInt(int c) {
    int ret = 0;
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return ret * 10 + c - '0';
    }
    return -1;
}
```

But I don't want to create StringBuilder on each step. How can I do it?

P.S I know about `BufferedReader's readLine()` method and `StringTokinizer` and this does not fit. I need to read bytes. I solve problems with storage this data and I need fast reading only.

It is an example of an interview task and I need to read a big array of values ​​with memory constraints.

Answer (score -2):

What about writing it to System.out while you read the data

```
@Test
public void read() throws IOException {
    int c;
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    while ((c = System.in.read()) != '\n') {
        int i = readInt(c);
        if (i != -1) {
            System.out.print(""+i);
        }else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n"); // end of line
}
```